# Can bash run a command when I hit enter on an empty line?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

[my environment](https://gist.github.com/mrbig033/63fd7f4f51b6a8ae379abae74c52aff2)

Is it possible to make bash run `clear && ls -A --color` whenever I hit enter on an empty line?

I don't know it that's relevant, but I'm using `set -o vi` for vi mode.

Answer (score 5):

This is possible by setting your PROMPT_COMMAND as such.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='h=$(fc -l -1); h=${h%% *}; (( h != oh )) || { clear && ls -A --color; }; oh=$h'
```

Comment: Doesn't work. You need to add parenthesis around `clear && ls -A --color`